# How to Run Powershell Code After Running "Uninstall-ADDSDomainController" and Restarting

Tags: powershell, active-directory, scheduled-tasks, startup, powershell-5.0

I have a interesting challenge, I'm trying to make changes to a server to remove it from a locally installed AD server and re-add it to a externally hosted domain controller. The first step in this process is to uninstall the AD role, this process requires me to restart the system before continuing. Optimally I would like to have a series of scripts that would preform the entire operation for me. To accomplish this I've combined the "Uninstall-ADDSDomainController" command with "Register-ScheduledTask". Something like the following:

```
Register-ScheduledTask `
    -TaskName "Test_Job" `
    -RunLevel Highest `
    -User ("\Administrator") -Password $DefaultPassword `
    -Trigger (New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At ((Get-Date).AddMinutes(3))) `
    -TaskPath "\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs\" `
    -Action (New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "Powershell" -Argument ("-Command & '" + $DefaultPath + "Test.ps1' `"1`" `"" + $DefaultUsername + "`" `"" + $DefaultPassword + "`""))

$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $DefaultPassword -AsPlainText -Force

Uninstall-ADDSDomainController -ForceRemoval -LocalAdministratorPassword $SecurePassword -SkipPreChecks -Force -DemoteOperationMasterRole
```

This however doesn't seem to work correctly. The "Uninstall-ADDSDomainController" runs and reboots the system, but upon logging in, the code in "Test" hasn't run, if you run the script again and reboot, it will work correctly however. I believe what is going on is that the credentials are no longer valid after removing the server from it's AD service. You can actually see the affect of this if you inspect the schedule task in windows:

[image]

However, I'm at a loss to understand what credentials would be valid after removing the server from it's locally installed AD role.

Stated very simply what I'm trying to achieve is: I would like to run a powershell script after the "Uninstall-ADDSDomainController" has completed and restarted the system. Is this possible and if so how can it be done?

Comment: have you tried to register two different schedules? It could be a way ..

Comment: @LucasBF Sure I guess I could but I don't understand how this would resolve the issue, it seems to me the issue is related to the "Administrator" user account shifting, maybe a example in code would help me understand?